# How do you sharpen and balance quad cut mower blades?

Tags: lawn-mower

Lots of guides for sharpening and balancing the more typical straight blades, but I can't find anything on quad cut blades.

Is there something about them that makes them less susceptible to imbalance or something?

Can anyone provide any guidance on it?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a blade balance thing, just use it.

Probably see less because they are unusual/uncommon compared to straight blades.

If you can put the center hole of the blade on the balance jig widget, you can grind more from the low blade or the low two blades until it balances, just like a straight blade, but with more options for how it could be out of balance. Go slowly and check often.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cheap digital scale off ebay to equalize their weight based on the lightest blade.